# the axes in a openGL graph

Tags: opengl, axes

I am new to OpenGL. One simple question. Is it right to say that the axe which goes to the South is the "X" axe, the horitonal axe which goes to the right is the "Y" axe et the last vertical axe which goes to the North is the "Z" axe as in my picture ?

[OpenGL axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV4AV.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean by "OpenGL graph" the default coordinate system OpenGL uses, then this is wrong. By default +x goes to the right, +y to the top of the screen and +z comes out of the screen.

Usually in CG, you expect the camera to look along the negative z axis.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "comes out of the screen" ?

Comment: is this right ? [link] (https://learnopengl.com/img/getting-started/coordinate_systems_right_handed.png) ?